# Kubernetes API server not accessible from external through IP address

Tags: kubernetes

on the node that api server is running, when I call `curl localhost:8080/api`, I see following

```
{
  "kind": "APIVersions",
  "versions": [
    "v1"
  ],
  "serverAddressByClientCIDRs": [
    {
      "clientCIDR": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "serverAddress": "192.168.152.201:6443"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, if I do `curl 192.168.152.201:6443/api` on same machine, I do not get anything back.

Can anyone explain why this is the case and how I can access api server externally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related to routing and when you make a call `192.168.152.201` where your traffic is going to.

Could be one or multiple things, some things to check:

- Does one of your physical interfaces have `192.168.152.201` configured as its IP address? (ie, ensX, or ethX)
- What is your default route? What do you get if you type `ip route` (Linux)
- If `192.168.152.201` is not one of your physical interfaces, is it an outside service. How do you get from your default route to that?
- If `192.168.152.201` is, in fact, one of your physical interfaces, do you have any iptables (firewall rules) preventing access to `192.168.152.201:6443` and not `127.0.0.1:6443`